# How to make a line plot in R with time on x-axis

Tags: r, plot, line

I would like to create a line plot - on x-axis i need times and on y-axis corresponding values.

Here is my head of table:

```
 3:10:45 PM  22.65916    22.85276    22.45874
 3:11:17 PM  22.67199    22.84572    22.4558
 3:11:49 PM  22.65227    22.8443     22.44791
 3:12:21 PM  22.64929    22.84993    22.4558
 3:12:53 PM  22.65622    22.84572    22.45284
 3:13:25 PM  22.65027    22.84572    22.45385
 3:13:58 PM  22.64139    22.85699    22.46366
 3:14:30 PM  22.66408    22.8443     22.45678
 3:15:02 PM  22.64734    22.85558    22.46366
 3:15:34 PM  22.6552     22.86403    22.46073
```

My part of code is:

```
temp=read.table("data.txt", header = FALSE, sep="\t")
plot(temp$V2, type="o", col="red")
```

I can add lines for another column, but how to put time to x-axis?

Result should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)

p <- ggplot(mlt, aes(x=V1, y=value, col=variable))+
                                            geom_line()

p+
  scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format('%I:%M:%S %p')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL)
```

You can also specify the `limits` and `breaks` in `scale_x_datetime`

```
  lo <- with(mlt,as.POSIXct(strftime(min(V1),"%Y-%m-%d")))
  hi <- with(mlt,as.POSIXct(strftime(as.Date(max(V1))+1,"%Y-%m-%d"))-1)
  limits <- c(lo,hi)

  p +
    scale_x_datetime(breaks='1 hour',labels=date_format('%I:%M:%S %p'),
       limits=limits) +
       theme_bw() +
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
       xlab(NULL) +
       ylab(NULL)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("3:10:45 PM", "3:11:17 PM", "3:11:49 PM", 
"3:12:21 PM", "3:12:53 PM", "3:13:25 PM", "3:13:58 PM", "3:14:30 PM", 
"3:15:02 PM", "3:15:34 PM"), V2 = c(22.65916, 22.67199, 22.65227, 
22.64929, 22.65622, 22.65027, 22.64139, 22.66408, 22.64734, 22.6552
), V3 = c(22.85276, 22.84572, 22.8443, 22.84993, 22.84572, 22.84572, 
22.85699, 22.8443, 22.85558, 22.86403), V4 = c(22.45874, 22.4558, 
22.44791, 22.4558, 22.45284, 22.45385, 22.46366, 22.45678, 22.46366, 
22.46073)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names =
c(NA, -10L))

mlt <- melt(df, id.var='V1')
mlt$V1 <- as.POSIXct(mlt$V1, format='%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Comment: thank you so much - but can I ask you when you define df <- structure(list(V1 = c("3:10:45 PM"..... how can I paste easy all column - not write "time to time" ? I tried something like df <- structure(list(V1 = c(data$col1), V2 = c(data$col2), V3 = c(data$col3)... But it doesnt work :-(

Comment: @Incorigible It is the output of `dput` i.e after you read the dataset, say `df`. try `dput(df)`. If it is a large dataset, use `dput(head(df))` otherwise the output will be really big.